# вывод веса элемента при поиске по символу, Java

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist

Есть ArrayList химических элементов. Каждый элемент в ArrayList выглядит примерно так:

> Element,Number,Symbol,Weight,Boil,Melt,Density Vapour,Fusion,
> Hydrogen,1,H,1.01,20.46,13.96,71,0.45,0.06,

Данная функция возвращает массив со всеми данными элемента по символу элемента.

```
public static List<ChemicalElement> searchBySymbol(String symbol) {
    List<ChemicalElement> search = new ArrayList();     
    for(ChemicalElement chemicalElement:chemicalElements)
    {
        if(chemicalElement.getSymbol().equals(symbol))
        {
            search.add(chemicalElement);
        }
    }      
    return search;
}
```

Мне же нужно получить из результата поиска только вес элемента, для вычисления молекулярной массы. Как можно это сделать?

Comment: Ваша ф-я возвращает коллекцию элементов. Так и задумано? Т.е. теоретически она может вернуть два водорода.

Comment: Приложите код класса `ChemicalElement`.

Comment: И действительно - зачем вам возвращать коллекцию?

Comment: Сорри, я решила) я при выводе коллекции вывела только вес.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static double elementsWeightBySymbol(String symbol) throws IllegalStateException {
    List<ChemicalElement> elementsBySymbol = ChemicalElementDAO.searchBySymbol(symbol);
    if(elementsBySymbol.size() != 0){
        return elementsBySymbol.get(0).getWeight();
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException();
}
```

То есть с помощью функции в вопросе ищу массив из ArrayList и циклом for присваиваю вес к элементу. Я не уверена что 100% правильно, но работает.

Comment: А как так может быть, чтобы элементов с таким символом было более 1? И почему вы в таком случае возвращаете вес именно последнего(в коллекции) такого элемента?

Comment: Я бы кинул исключение, если искомого нет, а не возвращал бы 0.

Comment: Там файл с элементами, в нем нет повторов. Поэтому в этом случае пройдет.

Comment: А про исключение спасибо. Так и сделаю.

Comment: Я бы кидал исключение, если нашлось более 1 элемента. Это неоднозначность, решение которой, как я понял, в задаче не прописано.

Comment: Также, если вы писали базу данных сами, сделайте поле `symbol` уникальным.

Comment: Не, это не база данных, это файл. И я не писала его сама.

Comment: Изменил - раз вам неважно, какой это будет элемент - первый или последний - легче всего возвратить первый попавшийся, вместо того, чтобы перебирать все

Comment: @МарияЛинк если Вы решили Ваш вопрос, отметьте Ваш ответ как решение, для этого нажмите на галку под цифрой слева от ответа.